# may / might / might as well?

Tags: grammar

"You might as well get a taxi from the station. It'll be quicker than me coming in to get you."

I know may, might, and might as well are quite different. But would it be incorrect (meaningless) if I used "may" or "might" instead of "might as well" in the sentence above?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are the user who downvoted my answer, but, if you are, would you mind telling me what I can do to improve it? I'd be happy to rewrite it.

Comment: @JohnB. No, I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: Ok.  I didn't mean to assume anything; I just want to make sure that your question is answered.  Please let me know what you think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let's look at all three choices to see what the sentences mean in each case.*

---

"Might as well":

> Used to suggest doing something, often when there is nothing better to do. [[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/may-might-as-well)]

Now let's look at the sentences with "might as well":

> You might as well get a taxi from the station. It'll be quicker than me coming in to get you.

This essentially means

> **Get a taxi because it will be faster than me picking you up.**

---

"May":

> Used to ask or give permission. [[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/may)]

In our case, we are concerned with "giving" permission.

The sentences with "may" are:

> You may get a taxi from the station. It'll be quicker than me coming in to get you.

and it means

> **I am *allowing* you to get a taxi because it is faster than me picking you up.**

---

"Might":

> Used to express the possibility that something will happen or be done, or that something is true although not very likely. [[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/might)]

The sentences would be:

> You might get a taxi from the station. It'll be quicker than me coming in to get you.

and mean

> **There is a *chance* that you will get a taxi.  If you get one, it will be faster than me picking you up.**

*The sentence with "might" is unnatural; I would not recommend using "might" in this case.*

Comment: So, do you think a test with all these choices for the sentence above is not a standard test?

Comment: @BeatsMe That depends.  Would you mind providing some more context (the actual test question)?

Comment: "You ........... get a taxi from the station. It'll be quicker than me coming in to get you."           A) may         B) might            C) might also            D) might as well

Comment: @BeatsMe The question is not standard, but the most reasonable answer is (D).  It is unlikely that (A) is correct because one person is probably not *giving permission* to the other to get a taxi.  (B) is very unnatural, and my interpretation of it in my answer is a little bit of a stretch because I have never heard anything like that before.(C) is incorrect for obvious reasons.  (D) is natural and makes the most sense, so it is almost definitely the correct answer.  Nonetheless, the test is not standard.  Does that help?

Comment: If (A) is not likely to be correct, (B) is very unnatural, and (C) is incorrect, then why do you think it is not a standard test?

Comment: @BeatsMe A standard test has to have *one* correct answer, and the rest of the answers *must be incorrect.*  In this case, all of the answers are grammatical, so the "correct" answer is based on subjective criteria.  Even though the answer is (D), the test is not based on *objective* criteria, and is therefore *not* standard.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. Is English your first language, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @BeatsMe Yes, it is.  Would you mind upvoting and accepting my answer (if you see fit) so other users know that it successfully answered your question?  This will also prevent other users from wasting time drafting responses to a question that you consider to already be answered.  Thanks!

Comment: "You ........... get a taxi from the station. It'll be quicker than me coming in to get you." A) may also B) might too C) might also D) might as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111293/discussion-between-beatsme-and-john-b).